# Enable the user to pick a date from Calender for non consecutive date only in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker, calendar

I am new to the calendar. I have an array of dates which is **non-consecutive**. I want to select and highlight it initially. And, the **unhighlighted has to be non-clickable**, i.e. the user is only able to click on those dates that are in the array of dates list.

After exploring that I found a way that we can only disable for picking date through **start, end and date range only**.

I made a view model as

```
class DateSelectionVM: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var activeDate = [
        DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 12),
        DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 15),
        DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 18),
        DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 20),
        DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 21),
        DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 27)
    ]
    
    @Published var selectedDates: Set<DateComponents> = []
    
    var bounds: Range<Date> {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var dates: [Date] = []
        for component in activeDate{
            dates.append(calendar.date(from: component)!)
        }
        
        if let range = dates.dateRange {
            print("Date range: \(range.lowerBound) to \(range.upperBound)")
            
            return range
        } else {
            print("Array is empty")
        }
        
        return dates.first!..<dates.last!
    }
    
    
    init() {
        calulateDate()
    }
    
    private func calulateDate(){
        for date in activeDate{
            selectedDates.insert(date)
        }
    }
}
```

where I defined a **activeDate** which has to be displayed on the  Calender as selected and clickable.

I define my view as

```
struct DateSelectionView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var dateSelectionVM = DateSelectionVM()
    
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            VStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    HStack{
                        Text("Your Daily Streak")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .font(.title2)
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "flame")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("120")
                            .font(.title)
                            .bold()
                    }
                    Divider()
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 0, bottom: 5, trailing: 0))
                    Text("Engage daily")
                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 0, bottom: 5, trailing: 0))
                    
                    
                    MultiDatePicker("Select Dates", selection: $dateSelectionVM.selectedDates, in: dateSelectionVM.bounds)
                        .frame(height: 300)
                }
                
                .padding()
            }
            .background(.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.purple.opacity(0.2))
        .navigationTitle("Stack")
        
    }
}
```

The problem I faced was that I wasn't able to disable other dates than activeDate.
I know I gave a range of dates that is consecutive so, it permitted the user to click. Is there another way to fix this problem?

[image]

I have attached the image. But what I want is that I want to disable 13,14,16,17,19,22,23,24,25,26 as well. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: You return all the dates between first and the last date. Can you just return the active dates?

Comment: I think we can only control through Range<Date>. And I gave the range in the above, so it came as that.

Comment: can you select a disabled cell? maybe disable all of them and just select the desired ones?

Comment: No, a disabled cell can't be clickable which is my requirement. How can I disable all of them?

Comment: you'll have better luck if you use `@State` for your view data

Comment: Sorry Malhal, I didn’t get you what you mean to say?